# Video Hosting, Conversion, and Streaming Solution

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-hosting

I currently offer the option to my users to upload their own video and have it converted to FLV and MP4 on my website. Here are the logistics:

1) User uploads video onto website
2) Raw video is then transferred (via SFTP) to another hosting provider, then the video is converted using FFMpeg into FLV and MP4.

This works for small videos, however, I have found a couple issues:

1) It appears that videos aren't always encoded properly (this could be due to my need to improve with FFMpeg)
2) My current host provider is not a 'streaming' solution, so, videos can be slow to play and a bit difficult to deal with.

I'd like to receive some input, as my website grows, on a solution that will be much more beneficial and streamlined. I've looked at Hey!Watch as a possible solution, but they don't provide hosting. I've also looked a bit at Panda, but I'm not sure how (or if) that would integrate with my current host provider.

Overall, I am looking for 3 essential components of video:
1) Converting to FLV and M4V (<-- the format for iPhones, iPods right?)
2) Ability to play at half speed (slow motion).
3) Ability to create thumbnail
3) Streaming server

Any suggestions on different providers that are reliable and can help me would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Panda](http://pandastream.com/): an open source solution for video uploading, encoding and streaming.

Also here's an [article](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fadw0rd.ru%2F2009%2Fvideoservice-handmade%2F&sl=ru&tl=en&history_state0=). It's in russian, sbut translate.google.com helps :)

Comment: Open source solution or open source client APIs?

Answer (score 1):

As streaming server you can use Flash Media Server, Wowza, or RED5.

- FMS -is from Adobe
- Wowza - is mature alternative for FMS, there is option to buy virtual machine with Wowza on Amazon EC2
- RED5 - is Open Source, alternative it also quite mature

for conversion You can try this project: http://code.google.com/p/multimedia-conversion/

Answer (score 0):

Try [encoding.com](http://www.encoding.com/api), really easy to integrate using APIs, its fast and reliable. Encoding is done on ec2. But its a paid service.